# How to programmatically detect if google is blocking me from making any further requests?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, http-status-code-429

#### Context:

- I have a web scrapper running in a hosted web app in Heroku.
- It scrapes the google search page to get some required information.
- I am using the `request` package

#### This is my code:

```py
 # this is a method inside a class
 def get_weather_component(self):
        # Send request and store the webpage that comes as a response
        s = requests.Session()
        s.headers["User-Agent"] = self.USER_AGENT
        s.headers["Accept-Language"] = self.LANGUAGE
        s.headers["Content-Language"] = self.LANGUAGE
        html = s.get(self.url)
```

**Note:** I know that I can check the `status code` to see if it is [err 429](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429)

#### Issues:

- But can there be any other possible reason for the request being blocked that needs to be handled?
- What is the minimum time gap between requests required for Google?

Any suggestion gratefully received. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is an API for Google Search. Google has probably placed a limit on the number of requests coming from the same IP.

- slow down until you figure out the limit. (add a thread.sleep() or something like that)
- run it on several servers allowing you to appear to come from different IP addresses. (deploy your application in a containerized environment)
- stop trying to directly crawl Google for search data and try to use their
  [RESTful API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview) instead.

Answer (score -1):

```
import requests

headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
data = {
    "Accept-Language": self.LANGUAGE
    "Content-Language": self.LANGUAGE
}

r = requests.get(self.url, data=data, headers=headers)
print(r.status_code)
```

Comment: Hi, how does this code answer the question? Can you explain a bit? Thanks!